# Read Updated Resource file

Tags: c#, dll, resource-files

I am unable to read updated resource file (Dynamically updated) when it is placed in another class library, even if i build the class library dynamically.

i have tried with

```
al.exe /t:lib /embed:D:\SibiMathew1\ResourceApp3\ResourceLib\App_GlobalResources\Resource1.resx /out:D:\SibiMathew1\ResourceApp3\ResourceLib\bin\Debug\ResourceLib.dll
```

in command prompt